# how to dynamically change listview items styles during runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I am using VS2010 - wpf - C#

I have a listview that shows securities prices and I want to style the listview rows in three different ways :
green - red - and orange

I don't know how to write a C# code that would affect the styles of these listview items during runtime under some conditions that I have ???

I don't know if my question needs some more explanation but if it does please let me know

Best Regards to everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to do it at runtime instead of in the XAML?

I am assuming the red/green/orange has some kind of meaning. Setup a DataTrigger on the Listbox's ItemContainerStyle which modifies the color based on a value.

Here's an example using a property named Priority on the ListView items

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Priority}" Value="2">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Orange" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Priority}" Value="3">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Comment: @Moauayad I'm not sure what you're asking, but since you accepted my answer I am assuming you are OK

Comment: What if I want to change the color or value at run-time?

Comment: @SaudKhan Then change the bound property... for example, setting `Priority=2` would make it Orange, while `Priority=3` would make it Red.